# Central Authentication Service with spring

Tags: spring, tomcat, cas

I work with **jboos 7** and I use **spring** in my application

currently I want to use CAS (Central Authentication Service)

I download **cas-server-3.5.2** and I download  **apache-tomcat-7.0.47-windows-x64**

and I make **cas-server-webapp-3.5.2.war** under **apache-tomcat-7.0.47-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps**

and I have the interface of login when I make in browser this link : 
**MyIpAdress:8080/cas-server-webapp-3.5.2/login**

I want to know how can I integrate the concept of CAS with my application

ans also I want to know if it is better or not to use CAS with jboss 7 or with tomcat

Answer (score 1):

From your question I am assuming that you have the CAS server running and and you can login etc.

So what you wanna do next, is **letting your applications talk with the cas server**, in this context your application is a client of your cas server. To do this in a Java/Spring Application you have two main options:

1. [CAS Client for JAVA](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/CAS+Client+for+Java+3.1)
2. [Spring Security CAS Client](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Spring+Security+%28previously+Acegi%29+as+CAS+Client)

For some general information about CAS Client integration you could also have a look at this [tutorial](http://mauriziostorani.wordpress.com/2008/08/23/central-authentication-service-cas-concepts-and-examples/).